# Multiple forms with single file input asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

Okay so I got this view which accepts model IEnumerable and foreach SomeModel inside Model renders a new partial view in which it passes single SomeModel. Inside this partial view I got a form which enables me to edit or add new of SomeModels. The thing is these forms have a file input. And only the first form input file worked, I realised why, all forms share same input file id's and label for's. So I tried adding them dynamicly:

```
    @{ 
        string idname = "file" + Model.Id;
    }
    <label for="@idname"><i class="far fa-image main-cat-icon"></i></label>
    <input type="file" name="@idname"/>
```

But now the labels wont work as expected. And for aesthetic reasons i hide the input itself and make label an icon to fit my app. I saw that `display: none;` can cause problems so I used:

```
.main-acp-button-cat input[type="file"] {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    float: left;
}
```

My controller expects 
    public ActionResult ActionTest(SomeModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file)

Is there another way of doing this? Or am I on the right track just missing something?

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "*now the labels wont work as expected*" actually means "*now when I click on the label it no longer sets focus to the file input element*"...

that would be because the `for` attribute of the `label` element references the target element's `id` attribute.  You have not given your `input` element an `id` attribute, so there is nothing to match.

You have 2 options.

1. Remove the `label`'s `for` attribute and place the `input` element within the body of the `label` element.
2. Assign an `id` attribute to the `input` element that matches the `label`'s `for` attribute value.

Comment: Of course it was something simple and I am too tired to see it. Thank you a lot. I had problems with setting up the id's and for's but I just skipped to your second suggestion which worked like a charm. Thank you again. ^^